# UITableViewController not resizing on input

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a number of TextFields defined in it.  In the 4.3 simulator, when I touch a TextField which is where the keyboard will cover it, the field is repositioned so that it's above the keyboard.  However, when I run the code on my iPhone, the repositioning doesn't happen.  Anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'll answer my own question even though I'm not sure what is going on.  When I disconnected my phone from the computer, and then ran the app that was copied over to it when I was debugging, the UITableViewController works as expected (moving the textfield above the keyboard).